# Getting this error while runing mvn install

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

I was trying to run a maven project in eclipse ide, i did maven clean then maven install and this error came. BUILD failure

Comment: I suppose you have failing tests...

Answer (score 0):

Try run maven install with skip test:

```
mvn clean install -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

and post the log.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).